# PHP-XML: How do I modify text value of a given target

Tags: php, xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xliff>
    <body>
        <trans-unit id="NFDBB2FA9-tu4" xml:space="preserve">
            <source xml:lang="en">He</source>
            <target xml:lang="id">He</target>
        </trans-unit>
        <trans-unit id="NFDBB2FA9-tu5" xml:space="preserve">
            <source xml:lang="en">She</source>
            <target xml:lang="id">She</target>
        </trans-unit>
    </body>
    <body>
        <trans-unit id="NFDBB2FA9-tu6" xml:space="preserve">
            <source xml:lang="en">They</source>
            <target xml:lang="id">They</target>
        </trans-unit>
        <trans-unit id="NFDBB2FA9-tu7" xml:space="preserve">
            <source xml:lang="en">We</source>
            <target xml:lang="id">We</target>
        </trans-unit>
    </body>
</xliff>
```

how do I modify value of `<target>` of `trans-unit id="NFDBB2FA9-tu7"` or any other?

done this but empty on the `print_r` and don't know what's next

```php
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->load("my.xlf");
$root = $dom->documentElement;
$xliffBodies = $root->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0);

foreach ($xliffBody as $body) {
    $el = $body->getElementsByTagName("trans-unit");
    print_r($el);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below is using a string representation of the original XML file (`my.xlf`) for convenience - change the `loadXML` for `load` to load your file.

If you use an `XPath` expression you can target these elements directly  - though here I targeted the `trans-unit` node initially before selecting the child node - `target`

```
<?php

    $strxml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xliff>
    <body>
        <trans-unit id="NFDBB2FA9-tu4" xml:space="preserve">
            <source xml:lang="en">He</source>
            <target xml:lang="id">He</target>
        </trans-unit>
        <trans-unit id="NFDBB2FA9-tu5" xml:space="preserve">
            <source xml:lang="en">She</source>
            <target xml:lang="id">She</target>
        </trans-unit>
    </body>
    <body>
        <trans-unit id="NFDBB2FA9-tu6" xml:space="preserve">
            <source xml:lang="en">They</source>
            <target xml:lang="id">They</target>
        </trans-unit>
        <trans-unit id="NFDBB2FA9-tu7" xml:space="preserve">
            <source xml:lang="en">We</source>
            <target xml:lang="id">We</target>
        </trans-unit>
    </body>
</xliff>';

    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadXML($strxml);
    
    $xp=new DOMXPath($dom);
    $xp->registerNamespace('xml','http://www.example.com');
    
    $col=$xp->query( '//xliff/body/trans-unit' );
    if( $col && $col->length ){
        foreach( $col as $node ){
            $target=$xp->query('target',$node)->item(0);
            $target->nodeValue='banana';
        }
    }
    
    printf('<textarea cols=50 rows=10>%s</textarea>',$dom->saveXML());

?>
```

A simple edit - change the `target` value to the word `banana` yields:

[image: Example output]

The original snippet of XML is a little different from the actual XML in that there are `namespace` declarations which mean you need to adopt a slightly different approach. [More Information on Namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registernamespace.php)

The default namespace needs to be used in the query, like so:

```
<?php

    $id='NFDBB2FA9-tu26';
    
    $file='my.xlf';

    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->load( $file );
    
    $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
    # We need to use this in the XPath query - this could be almost anything but best kept short!!
    $xp->registerNamespace('f','urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2');
    
    # Not essential to declare the following when simply querying against the default namespace
    $xp->registerNamespace('okp','okapi-framework:xliff-extensions');
    $xp->registerNamespace('its','http://www.w3.org/2005/11/its');
    $xp->registerNamespace('itsxlf','http://www.w3.org/ns/its-xliff/');
    $xp->registerNamespace('xml','http://www.example.com');
    
    # note how each portion of the XPath expression uses our namespace prefix..
    $col=$xp->query( '//f:xliff/f:file/f:body/f:trans-unit[@id="'.$id.'"]/f:target' );
    
    
    
    if( $col && $col->length ){
        foreach( $col as $node ){
            $node->nodeValue='Big Bold Brave Banana';
        }
    }
    
    printf('<textarea cols=180 rows=40>%s</textarea>',$dom->saveXML());

?>
```

Comment: could it target a specific target inside a given <trans-unit id> ?

Comment: yes - you can be very specific wit hthe XPath expression. If you know an ID or a particular attribute you can build the Xpath expression to explicitly target that element

Comment: I'm reproducing on this but can't get it to work. http://xpather.com/HJhVshob . this is what I've done : https://pastebin.com/uEMMkC1s . it returns 0 on DOMNodeList

Comment: [Perhaps a quick read of the PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) manual might help? Essentially your XPath expression is missing the initial `//` and does not use the [default namespace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registernamespace.php) in the XPath expression

Comment: on this: `$node->nodeValue='Big Bold Brave Banana';`. if I insert it as html code, e.g. `$node->nodeValue='<some id="1">Big Bold Brave Banana';` . this is not encoded . how do I encode it?

Comment: either `htmlspecialchars` or add within a `cdata` section